# Correlation matrix with 150 variables, how to visualize it in R?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a dataset of 150 variables and I want to somehow show a correlation matrix. I tried with corrplot and many other proposed ways online but I could not manage to get a decent output. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? You can turn off the clustering with `cluster_rows =FALSE` etc and you might need to play around to make the labels visible:

```
library(pheatmap)
dat = matrix(rnorm(10*150),ncol=150)
colnames(dat) = paste0("Var",1:ncol(dat))
COR = cor(dat)
pheatmap(COR,fontsize=4)
```

[image]

We can try using a data (gene expression),[golub](https://github.com/cran/multtest/blob/master/data/golub.RData) or you can call it from `library(multtest)` that has some structure (because genes are often correlated in expression). I also pulled out 150 genes that are most correlated with the phenotype:

```
load("golub.RData")
topvar = order(abs(cor(t(golub),golub.cl)),decreasing=TRUE)[1:150]
dat = t(golub[topvar,])
colnames(dat) = paste0("Var",1:ncol(dat))
COR = cor(dat)
pheatmap(COR,fontsize=4)
```

[image]

This is a bit extreme but in general, if there is structure you will see it from this visualization.

Comment: This is better than a plain `ggplot2::geom_tile`, which is the approach I was taking (hence the upvote) but either way unless the variables have some sort of pattern to them, the whole concept of a 150 x 150 correlation plot seems a bit flawed

Comment: yeah.. good point. Thanks for the feedback. I was using an example dataset but found it too much info. I have included it in the answer now

Comment: This is great! Thank you